# how to use append function in file

Tags: java, java-io

I want to write in a file but in a way that it should not delete existing data in that file rather it should append that file. Can anybody please help by giving any example related to appending a file? Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738448/java-i-o-how-to-append-to-an-already-existing-text-file already answered

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [`FileWriter(File file, boolean append)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)) constructor with the boolean value **`true`**.

**Example**

```
File file = new File("c:/tmp/foo.txt");
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true)));
pw.println("Hello, World");
pw.close();
```

Comment: can you please provide me full code including import statements etc because i am having problem in understanding and running this code. thanks

Comment: no sir i asked for the complete code. not only the import statement.

Comment: this error is shown in my program when i compile it:

cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor FileWriter(boolean,boolean)
location: class java.io.FileWriter
 PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true)));                             
                                                     
1 error

Comment: The compiler error suggests you are passing in two booleans rather than a File parameter and a boolean.