# Add to file instead of overwriting

Tags: java, csv

I have written a program that scraped source code twice, and created A CSV with specific information from the retrieved data. My issue is, when I go to save the second bit of data, instead of adding to the created CSV, it overwrites it with the new information. I have referred to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269302/how-do-you-append-to-a-text-file-instead-of-overwriting-it-in-java), but it is using a different class. My code is currently:

```
  public static void scrapeWebsite() throws IOException {


    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(s);
    originalHtml = page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
    obtainInformation();
    originalHtml = "";
    final HtmlForm form = page.getForms().get(0);
    final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByValue(">");
    final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
    try {
      synchronized (page2) {
        page2.wait(1000);
      }
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
      System.out.println("error");
    }
    originalHtml = originalHtml + page2.refresh().getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
    obtainInformation();
  }

  public static void obtainInformation() throws IOException {

     PrintWriter docketFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("tester3.csv", true));
```

// creates the csv file. (name must be changed, override deletes file)
        originalHtml = originalHtml.replace('"','*');
        int i = 0;

```
    //While loop runs through all the data in the source code. There is (14) entries per page.
    while(i<14) {
      String plaintiffAtty = "PlaintiffAtty_"+i+"*>"; //creates the search string for the plaintiffatty
      Pattern plaintiffPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<="+Pattern.quote(plaintiffAtty)+").*?(?=</span>)");//creates the pattern for the atty
      Matcher plaintiffMatcher = plaintiffPattern.matcher(originalHtml); // looks for a match for the atty

      while (plaintiffMatcher.find()) {
        docketFile.write(plaintiffMatcher.group().toString()+", "); //writes the found atty to the file
      }
      i++;
    }
    docketFile.close(); //closes the file 
  } 
}
```

I believe the change will have to be made in the second method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `PrintWriter` should reference a [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.htm) constructed with the append constructor boolean set to true.

e.g

```
new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("myfile.csv", true));
```

Note the Javadoc for `FileWriter` re. your encoding specification:

> Convenience class for writing character files. The constructors of
>   this class assume that the default character encoding and the default
>   byte-buffer size are acceptable. To specify these values yourself,
>   construct an OutputStreamWriter on a FileOutputStream.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to append to a file, but not opening your PrintWriter in append mode.

Refer to [PrintWriter append method not appending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210616/printwriter-append-method-not-appending)