# append to existing xml file

Tags: java, xml, append

I had created a method to write on xml file my infos

```
Element performances = new Element("performances");
Document doc = new Document(performances);

performances.setAttribute(new Attribute("date", dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())));

//Uptime
                Element uptime = new Element("uptime");
                uptime.addContent(new Element("days").setText(new Long(duptime).toString()));
                uptime.addContent(new Element("hours").setText(new Long(huptime).toString()));
                uptime.addContent(new Element("minutes").setText(new Long(muptime).toString()));
                uptime.addContent(new Element("seconds").setText(new Long(suptime).toString()));
                doc.getRootElement().addContent(uptime);
                //TotalHitsCount
                doc.getRootElement().addContent(new Element("totalhitcount").setText(new Long(stats.gettotal_hit_count()).toString()));
                //EmittedBytes
                doc.getRootElement().addContent(new Element("emittedbytes").setText(new Long(stats.getemitted_bytes()).toString()));
                //Avghitsec
                doc.getRootElement().addContent(new Element("avghitsec").setText(new Float(stats.getavg_hit_sec()).toString()));
                //Avgbyteshit
                doc.getRootElement().addContent(new Element("avgbyteshit").setText(new Long(stats.getavgbytes_hit()).toString()));
                //Avgbps
                doc.getRootElement().addContent(new Element("avgbps").setText(new Long(stats.getavgbps()).toString()));
                //Total threads
                doc.getRootElement().addContent(new Element("totalthreads").setText(new Long(stats.gettotal_threads()).toString()));
                //Idle threads
                doc.getRootElement().addContent(new Element("idlethreads").setText(new Long(stats.getidle_threads()).toString()));

                XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();

                xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
                xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter("/home/mazzy/Scrivania/perfor_"+dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())+".xml"));
```

instead to recreate a new file everytime, I would create the first time the file and at the second writing append the infos on the existing file

Comment: Do you mean append a whole new DOM after the existing one? If so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738448/java-i-o-how-to-append-to-an-already-existing-text-file?rq=1

Comment: yes I would append a new dom after the existing one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) class has a constructor for that with the append parameter.
So your code would look like this:

```
xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter("/home/mazzy/Scrivania/perfor_"+dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())+".xml"), true);
```